# Using parameter in jq 'any' does not result in right answer

Tags: json, jq

I am using jq lib in GitLab to parse deployment info from dynamic JSON to determine if deployments should be made. I am not able to get jq `any(condition)` working with dynamic attributes:

```
jq 'any(.name == "$my_value")'
```

Above returns always false, I've assigned a value `dolle` into `my_value`. If however, I run the same code like so, it returns true (as it should):

```
jq 'any(.name == "dolle")'
```

Here the json array that I give to jq:

```
[{ "name": "dolle" }, { "name": "polle" }]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post your JSON and show us an expected output

Comment: The JSON is the array I put in the example. I wonder if select is truly mandatory as my example works if I hard code the value any is comparing .name against.

Comment: shell variables don't expand inside single quote. Use the `--arg` syntax to pass a shell variable to jq context